# Did my flags get rejected because of flagging this spammer?

Tags: support, flags, spam, declined-flags

[Account 1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/716352/mis510proj) and [account 2](https://stackoverflow.com/users/718158/mis510proj).

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5725074/how-to-get-masters-project-highest-in-google-search-for-mis510proj?noredirect=1* (deleted now)

*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5738634/how-to-increase-ranking-for-specific-keyword-such-as-mis510proj* (deleted now)

Comment: Any clue in http://stackoverflow.com/users/flag-weight/213464 (which only YOU can see)? Or is that how you saw your flags were declined?

Comment: Umm, what spammer? (clears away smoke)

Comment: @Arjan, flag summary page is useful for history, but does not say it is rejected or approved. But it is easy to observe, if the post is still not deleted and when I lose -10, then flag is rejected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your flag weight went down (and you're sure that it was those flags that were dismissed), someone might have seen the 'researchy' aspect of the question and decided not to take action.

I, however support academia. Spammers often see accounts obliterated on site, and this should be reflected in research. All kidding aside, SPAM is SPAM, the accounts weren't even registered and the questions were extremely off topic. Stack Overflow isn't anyone's personal "Google Juice" tool, academic or otherwise.